# Failed to Install Data-Fixtures with Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I added the docrtine-fixtures and the doctrine-fixtures-bundle to my dependencies in the composer.json, as follow:

```
 {
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/finder": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "~1.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0"

    }
}
```

And then I did php-cli composer.phar update, which worked and displayed the right message on my terminal:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>     - Updating doctrine/data-fixtures (dev-master bd44f6b => v1.1.1)
>       Checking out bd44f6b6e40247b6530bc8abe802e4e4d914976a
>
> Writing lock file
>
> Generating autoload files

Bu when I go to the folder vendor/doctrine, I cannot find any data-fixtures repository. What is the issue? Why does composer not load it and why does it display success messages?

(PS: My solution was to add the doctrine-fixture repository manually but it doesn't solve the composer issue).

Comment: Add the output of `COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/dev/null composer require 'doctrine/data-fixtures:~1.1' && doctrine update doctrine/data-fixtures && ls -la ./vendor/doctrine/` to the question please. Run the command with the CWD where your `composer.json` is located.

Comment: Hi Matteo, I cannot figure out where exactly I should add the output you are suggesting.

I tried to put "COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR":"/dev/null," in my composer.json juste before "require":{} and then type php-cli composer.json update data-fixtures but it did the same thing.

The commande doctrine update doesn't exist, so I did php-cli app/console doctrine:update:data-fixtures but it displayed a fatal error message.

Could you help me out? What should I write and where (terminal, file?). Thanks.

Comment: I tried to "rm -rf ~/.composer/cache" as GM suggested, and then delete the doctrine-fixtures-bundle" and do php-cli composer.phar require 'doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle:~2.2' and then php-cli composer.phar update but it keeps displaying:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

But it doesn't download any repository to the vendor/doctrine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a Composer caching issue. Try removing Composer's cache directory:

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```

Comment: Hi GM,

I tried to delete the cache but it would do exactly the same thing, without doanloading the right repositories to MyApp/vendor/doctrine.

Comment: You could also try the procedure described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462185/composer-not-downloading-src-directory-for-packages If that doesn't work it might be necessary to reinstall composer. Hope that helps.